# No module named 'virtualenvwrapper'

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, virtualenvwrapper

I am working to set up a Django project on Amazon EC2 with an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS instance. I want to write my code using Python 3. I've been advised that the best way to do this is to use `virtualenvwrapper`. I've installed `virtualenvwrapper` successfully and put

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3.4
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

into my `.bashrc` file. Now I see:

```
 /usr/bin/python3.4: Error while finding spec for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' (<class 'ImportErro
 r'>: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper')
 virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.     

 If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
 check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
 VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3.4 and that PATH is
 set properly.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you installed `virtualenvwrapper` successfully **for that version of Python**? If you run `/usr/bin/python3.4` in the terminal and then try to `import virtualenvwrapper`, what happens?

Comment: ImportError: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper' - I guess not. I installed it for the base interpreter with is python 2.7 here

Comment: You probably need to `pip3 install virtualenvwrapper` to get it installed for the 3.x interpreter. Alternatively, note that `virtualenvwrapper` installed under 2.x *can* still create 3.x `virtualenv`s, using the `-p` parameter (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/1534210/3001761).

Comment: Thank you, you got it working! Would you mind putting in an answer? I've gone with your second suggestion. Please see the edit.

Comment: You shouldn't edit the outcome into the question - I'm happy for you to take what you've learned and write your own answer, instead!

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you very much for that comment to hit that one needs to check if the python interpreter that has virtualenvwrapper installed is also the one set in `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON`.

Answer (score 43):

Instead of specifying a different python interpreter with `-p` flag, you can also config your desired interpreter as default.

According to `virtualenvwrapper`'s [documentation](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html), `virtualenvwrapper.sh` finds the first `python` and `virtualenv` programs on the `$PATH` and remembers them to use later.

If your `virtualenvwrapper` is not installed on your OS's default python interpreter (`/usr/bin/python`), make sure you override the environment variables as below:

- `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON` to the full path of your python interpreter
- `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV` to the full path of the virtualenv

For example, on my `.bash_profile` (Mac):

```
#virtualenvwrapper
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/virtualenv
source /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Reload your new variables by running `source ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: This issue seems prevalent on Macs, but if you're on Ubuntu, you'll want to use '/usr/bin/python3', 'usr/local/bin/virtualenv', and '/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh', assuming you've installed to the default locations.

Answer (score 39):

I had the same problem after the recent Homebrew updates.

In the past, most people would have run `pip install virtualenvwrapper` into the system site packages and it would have worked.

Homebrew broke this workflow by 1) no longer shadowing the system python, and 2) no longer symlinking pip to `pip2/pip3`.

Most users will realize this when they can't find `pip`, and then try to use `pip2/pip3`. However, using `pip2/pip3` will create a problem because `virtualenvwrapper` is now installed for `python2/python3`, but not for `python`. So when `virtualenvwrapper` runs and calls python, it won't find the `virtualenvwrapper/virtualenv` python packages in the system python's site packages.

Explicitly setting `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON` is the cleanest fix, and not a hack. Here's how I did it in my dotfiles

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3
```

Comment: tnx. need to set `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON` before `WORKON_HOME`.

Comment: Same exact problem. I fixed it by keeping virtualenvwrapper installed on both py2 (pip) and py3 (pip3)

Answer (score 16):

On Ubuntu 20.04, the problem can occur when trying to install virtualenvwrapper with python 3.8 (python 3 default) and init the wrapper with python 2.7 (python 2 default).

### TL;DR

Manually set python3 interpreter

```sh
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=$(which python3)
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

### In more details, Why does this happen?

Let's get some informations:

```sh
$ which python
/usr/bin/python

$ python --version
Python 2.7.18rc1

$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3

$ python3 --version
Python 3.8.2

$ pip3 --version
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

Following the guidelines, we are asked to install virtualenvwrapper with pip (python 3):
`pip3 install virtualenvwrapper`

Current stable version (4.8.4) of virtualenvwrapper is [linking to default `python` version](https://bitbucket.org/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper/src/aa2ac7fcbe0d3c97e4bba0a4098d504a89d67d69/virtualenvwrapper.sh#lines-50), which we saw it's python 2.7:

```
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON="$(command \which python)"
```

So, the problem is that we installed virtualenvwrapper in python3 and try to init with python2 (sourcing shell script). The fix is therefore to init with python 3 by overriding default.

But, it is very likely that one of the next releases will include a [fix already merged onto master that look from highest to lowest python version](https://bitbucket.org/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper/commits/b71ddca0837cf193b1e8bb05f3c4e2c937913bb4):

```sh
if [ "${VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON:-}" = "" ]
then
    for NAME in python3 python2 python
    do
        python_executable="$(which $NAME 2>/dev/null)"
        if ! [ -z "$python_executable" ]
        then
            if $python_executable -m 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' --help >/dev/null 2>&1
            then
                VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=$python_executable
                break
            fi
        fi
    done
```

[Using in the documentation](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#python-interpreter-virtualenv-and-path), the fix is to manually set the Python interpreter to use before sourcing: **Not python (2.7) but python3 (3.8 here)**

```sh
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=$(which python3)
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Answer (score 8):

If you use brew to install python, you will want to ensure that you set this environment variable:

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python
```

in your bash_profile (or whatever shell you are using).

Answer (score 8):

Since I change python versions every now and then, this configuration has been working so far, since it's dynamic:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/development
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=$(which python3)
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=$(which virtualenv)
source $(which virtualenvwrapper.sh)
```

And then followed by:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you are using the correct version of python. In my case I was using

```
\usr\bin\python3
```

Instead of

```
\usr\local\bin\python3.7
```

Answer (score 1):

Following Jon's advice I ran:

```
 ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~$ mkvirtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.4 env1
 Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3.4
 Using base prefix '/usr'
 New python executable in env1/bin/python3.4
 Also creating executable in env1/bin/python
 Installing setuptools, pip...done.
 (env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~$ deactivate
 ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~$ ls
 ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~$ ls -a
 .  ..  .bash_history  .bash_logout  .bashrc  .cache  .pip  .profile  .ssh  .virtualenvs
 ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~$ workon
 env1
 ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~$ workon env1
 (env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~$ which python
 /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env1/bin/python
 (env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~$  python -V
 Python 3.4.0
```

I've left the .bashrc as listed above. As Jon stated above installing virtualenvwrapper installs on the default python, and uses the default python in any virtualenv you create unless the -p flag is used to specify a different python interpreter.

Comment: Please ensure that this is a useful, standalone answer - i.e. explaining *why* this works (and including, presumably, the changes you've made to `.bashrc`).

Answer (score 1):

For those facing the same issues while using Ubuntu 18.04, please note that
.bashrc needs the following edits.

Change `source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` to

```
source ~/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

NOTE that local directory is hidden

Answer (score 1):

No solution above helped me.

Here is my way which was working for me:

```
# if doesn't work try sudo pip uninstall virtualenvwrapper
pip uninstall virtualenvwrapper
# rm old virtualenv scripts
rm ~/.local/bin/virtualenv*
# re-install viertualenv
pip install --user  virtualenvwrapper
```

Answer (score -1):

My Unified OpenCV environment setup function that works seamlessly across MAC and Linux environments...

[image]

Comment: @Shree : check this answer...hope its helpful to future visitors. Upvote if you please.

Comment: Please keep the answer in text and not paste image