# Installing virtualenvwrapper on Mac (osx 10.12.5)

Tags: macos, python-3.x, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I have been have a tough time to install virtualenvwrapper, I see that I have installed python 3, also installed virtualenvwrapper by running

```
pip3 install virtualenvwrapper
```

then adding there three lines on .bash_profile

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs 
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

but it gives me

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory
-bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory
-bash: /Users/user/.bash_profile: line 43: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
-bash: /Users/user/.bash_profile: line 46: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I though it may be not on the path /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh. Run find / -name virtualenvwrapper.sh, but no luck (just a lots of permission denide lines) How can I figure out?

virtualenv itself works, just need to setup vertalenvwrapper, thank you.

Comment: did you try `which virutalenvwrapper.sh`? (src: https://teamtreehouse.com/community/installing-virtualenvwrapper-on-mac-osx-yosemite)

Comment: Yes I have tried it but the same result. 

    
    source `which virtualenvwrapper.sh`

but the same out come

Comment: ok, maybe try inspecting `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.x/bin/` directory, change `3.x` to the python version. (src: [Where is virtualenvwrapper.sh after pip install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647266/where-is-virtualenvwrapper-sh-after-pip-install))

Comment: Oh, I am not sure how I can inspect the directories! Could you possibly tell me?

Comment: Sure, in your `Terminal` shell, type `ls` (lowercase LS) to "list" the contents of directories, so type command `ls /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/` then press `tab` key to see the directories of Python Versions. So if you have Python 3.4, for example, type `ls /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/` and see if `virtualenvwrapper.sh` is in the `bin` folder

Comment: Thank you, but I am on myname ~$ on bash, do I have to come out from it? and how?x

Comment: I think that that will work too. after the `$` prompt in bash, type `ls /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/` and press enter

Comment: yes, there is !! I was typing wrong :0

Comment: great  try using that path in your `.bash_profile`

Comment: Thanks, I added source /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh but it gives me exactly the same error.

Yes exactly, -bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory. Why does .bash_profile not taking my new source?

Comment: this is the whole error,
    `-bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory`
    `-bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory`
    `-bash: /Users/satokoichimura/.bash_profile: line 43: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''`
    `-bash: /Users/satokoichimura/.bash_profile: line 59: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

I am not sure if there is some file corruption, or may be because I am doing it for version 3.6 which is not really supported.

Comment: did you try that same command on bash at a command prompt? `source /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/virtua‌​lenvwrapper.sh`, see if that gives you the same error?

Comment: I just tried what you suggested then it gives me 

`/usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks. 

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.`
So I tried `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/Library/Frameworks/Python.Framework/Versions/3.6/bin` on bash_profile then tried again your suggestion on command prompt but the same comment came up...

Comment: It seems like your system python default is still `python2.7`. Could you share what is the output of `/usr/bin/python -V`?

Comment: I found this, [basic links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29149853/no-module-named-virtualenvwrapper) I will follow the suggestion of export for VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON and VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV

Comment: yes my out put is Python 2.7.10
I was not sure how to set the default so when I check the version, I always do python3 and use pip3 command to install virtualenvwrapper

Comment: ok, sound good. just make sure you include `python` and `virtualenv` at the end of `export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3` and
`export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/virtualenv` as shown in the "basic links" answer you pointed to. Just change `python3` and `virtualenv` to the commands that exist in your `bin` directory

Comment: just done it but, but no luck. I checked if I wrongly typed many. `export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/virtualenv
source /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
satokoichimura ~ $ source ~/.bash_profile
-bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory
-bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory
`

Comment: I think I need to look into this message
`-bash: /Users/satokoichimura/.bash_profile: line 43: unexpected EOF while looking for matching \`''
-bash: /Users/satokoichimura/.bash_profile: line 81: syntax error: unexpected end of file`
these shows up every time tried `source ~/.bash_profile`.
bash somehow don't read these export and source with some reason. Would you have any ideas? I have been searching through...

Comment: Yes, it sounds like there is an opening single quote `'` in `~/.bash_profile` that doesn't have a matching closing single quote `'` somewhere in the file, possibly somewhere around `line 43`

Answer (score 0):

I decided move on to anaconda env as I needed so many libraries (& jupyter notebook) to use. Still don't know how it could be worked out.